# Display Many to Many in Show Blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have a members, interests and interests_members table where 1 member can have multiple interests and 1 interest can be shared by multiple members. When testing the interests_members table update 100%.

The interests_members table have the following columns:

1. id
2. interest_id -> foreign key
3. member_id -> foreign key

My problem is, I don't know what syntax to use in order to display the interests per member in the show blade? In need help with the **Interest** field in the code block below.

show.blade.php:

```
<h1>Member Details: </h1>
<p>Name: {{$member->name}}</p>
<p>Surname: {{$member->surname}}</p>
<p>ID Nr: {{$member->id_number}}</p>
<p>Language: {{$member->language->name}}</p> 
<p>Interest: {{??????}}</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have your relationships in place:

```
class Member extends Model {
    public function interests() {
        return $this->hasMany(Interest::class);
    }
}

class Interest extends Model {
    public function members() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Member::class);
    }
}
```

This will mean in your view you can do (example):

```
<p>Interests:</p>
<ul>
    @foreach($member->interests as $interest)
        <li>{{ $interest->name }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

This explains how many-to-many relationships work: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

you can define relationships in the Interest and Member models base on the [documentations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

after defining the relations you can get Member interests using `$yourMember->interests()`

Answer (score -1):

```
class MeemberInterest extends Model {
    public function interest() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Interest');
    }
    public function member() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Member');
    }
}

class Member extends Model {
    public function interests() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\MemberInterest')->with('interest');
    }
}

class Interest extends Model {
    public function members() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Member::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, would anyone tell me, how the accepted solution worked? His, interests table and members table are not directly related but, related through third table, member_interest. So, how does the accepted answer work?